# (Laravel) How to associate foreign key of a foreign key in model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have 3 table with this fields :

```
User:
id
name
address

Employee:
id
user_id

Profile:
id
employee_id
```

how can i associate `user->name` from `Profile` model

```
class Profile extends Model
{

    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee', 'employee_id');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', $employee->user_id);
    }
}
```

The `user()` function is obviously wrong, T'm trying to get the user data from the `Profile`. what is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Use HasOneThrough relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make **belongsTo** in both Model. `Profile` **belong** with `Employee` and `Employee` belong with `User`

```
class Profile extends Model
{

    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee', 'employee_id');
    }
}


class Employee extends Model
{

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

In your controller you can get user data using profile like this.

```
$profile = Profile::with('employee.user')->first();
echo $profile->employee->user->name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use HasOneThrough relationship.

```
class Profile extends Model
{

    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee', 'employee_id');
    }
    /**
     * Get the User
     */
     public function user()
     {
        return $this->hasOneThrough('App\User', 'App\Employee');
     }
}
```

Now, You can access user name like,

```
$profile->user->name
```

You can see the example usage in laravel official documentation here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through

Comment: Thank you for your input, i tried to query this but it gave me an error 



`public function index()
    {
        $profile= Profile::with('user','employee')->get();
        dd($profile->user);
        return view('profile.index');
    }`

Comment: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.profile' in 'field list'`

Comment: Since you don't have profile column in the users table this error was encountered. You have to load relationship from profile model to user model like profile.user not user.profile